# Magento2 : How To Get Shipping Amount Order Item Wise

Tags: magento2, shipping

I want to get shipping  amount order items wise

e.g :

```
products      Shipping Amounts
-------------------------------
Product 1     10


Product 2     5


Product 3     10 
----------------
Total Shipping  25
```

So I want to get a shipping amount of product1 only.
So does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: are you using any third-party shipment module?

Comment: it depends on which shipping method you are using and which logic is used in that shipping method so please post more details on it.

Comment: shipping calculation is based on magento2 core weight vs destination calculation